# PUT/DELETE giving 405 error with angular and WebAPI in VS Community 2015

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api, vs-community-edition

I am getting 405(Method not found) error in PUT and DELETE requests in my angular and WebAPI. GET and POST are working fine. I have checked all the solutions with this type of error on 'SO' but it didn't worked. I have added required handlers(with PUT/DELETE verbs) in my *WebConfig*, updated *applicationhost.config* of IIS EXpress and also uninstalled *WebDAV* module but still the problem persists.

Here is my controller code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/BlogPost")]
public class BlogPostController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/BlogPost
    public IQueryable<BlogPostModel> GetblogPostTb()
    {
        return db.blogPostTb;
    }

    // GET: api/BlogPost/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(BlogPostModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBlogPostModel(int id)
    {
        BlogPostModel blogPostModel = db.blogPostTb.Find(id);
        if (blogPostModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(blogPostModel);
    }

    // PUT: api/BlogPost/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutBlogPostModel(int id, BlogPostModel blogPostModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != blogPostModel.ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(blogPostModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!BlogPostModelExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(BlogPostModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteBlogPostModel(int id)
    {
        BlogPostModel blogPostModel = db.blogPostTb.Find(id);
        if (blogPostModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.blogPostTb.Remove(blogPostModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(blogPostModel);
    }
}
```

And here is the client side code:

```
var updateBlogPost = function (id, blogPost) {
        return $http.put(blogPostsUrl+"/"+id, blogPost)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response;
            })
```

Just for the info,I am working with WebAPI2, IIS Express 10 in Visual Studio Community 2015. I am not sure if this is the error of IIS EXpress 10 or Community version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the known issue with attribute routing with WebAPI.
Here update *AcceptVerbs* and *Route* attribute with DELETE and PUT methods like this :

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
[Route("{id:int}")]
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
public IHttpActionResult PutBlogPostModel(int id, BlogPostModel blogPostModel)
{
 // Your code
}
```

And Delete as :

```
[ResponseType(typeof(BlogPostModel))]
[Route("{id:int}")]
[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteBlogPostModel(int id)
{
  // Your Code
}
```

And also use *AcceptVerbs* attribute for *GET* method as well because these three(GET,PUT,DELETE) have same URL structure to call their methods.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS Studio Community 2015. It is the way WebAPI is implemented

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks a lot. I was stuck in it from last 2 days. It just worked for me. Thanks again.